# ng-model into textarea doesn't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use this function to add some products code into a textarea with ng-click:

```
<textarea ng-model="rec.LOTTI">{{rec.lotti}}</textarea>

    <div ng-repeat="reci in recis">
      <div class="chip" ng-click="addTrack(reci.lotto)" style="float:left;margin:2px">
    {{reci.prodotto}}
    <i class="icon ion-plus-circled"></i>
  </div>
  </div>

$scope.addTrack = function(l){
    $scope.rec.lotti = $scope.rec.lotti+", "+l;
    console.log(l+$scope.rec.lotti);
}
```

The problem is that the ng-model value it's updated each time that I click, but inside the textarea I can't see anything!

Comment: You don't need `{{rec.lotti}}` in `textarea` element..as `ng-model` will do the trick for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not nessasry to have `{{rec.lotti}}` inside your textarea, when you have a `ng-model` (it's a two-way-binding). Another point is that `rec.lotti` is not `rec.LOTTI`; angular js is case-sensitive. Correct is:

```
<textarea ng-model="rec.lotti"></textarea>
```